# C#: Passing a pointer to the string to hold the returned value

Tags: c#

I am currently working on communication with a FANUC 31i model B controller. My goal is to able to uploaded a part program, verify there is no data loss, and delete the program when needed.

FANUC has a FOCAS library with helpful functions to use in C#. Below is the DllImport I am having trouble with.

```
/* read selected file name */
[DllImport("FWLIB64.dll", EntryPoint="cnc_pdf_rdmain")]
public static extern short cnc_pdf_rdmain( ushort FlibHndl, [Out,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] Object a );
```

According to their technical team I need to pass a pointer to a string to hold the returned value stored in Object a. The string is the file path of the part program that was just uploaded to the system. This is important to me as it will allow me to select the uploaded program as the main program.

This is what I am using in my main code:

```
Object mg1 = new object();
        rslt = Focas64.cnc_pdf_rdmain(this.i31Handle, );
        if (rslt != 0)
        {
            StopActivity(true);
            return;
        }
```

I am not too familiar with C# or coding for that matter. So please dumb it down for me. Thank you!

Comment: Why the C++ tag when you are using C#?  They are different languages.

Comment: The FOCAS library was originally designed for C++. I thought it would be relevant in this situation. I will remove it for now

Comment: What is the exact signature of the `cnc_pdf_rdmain` function in the C or C++ header file?

Comment: Did you get this working?  One thing I've seen done before is passing StringBuilder into win32 api's, I'm looking at the Fanuc c# wrapper at the moment and their are some odd function declarations, it's difficult to know if they all work as there are samples of them all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue below is the working code:

```
        // Verify code
        byte[] a = new byte[244];
        rslt = Focas64.cnc_pdf_rdmain(this.i31Handle, a);
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a);
        if (rslt != 0)
        {
            StopActivity(true, Convert.ToString(rslt), this.tDownloadls, true);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the FANUC products you're talking about, but here are some string basics.
You can create a string like this

```
string myString;
```

then get a pointer to it like this

```
&myString;
```

So your code might look like this

```
string myString;
rslt = Focas64.cnc_pdf_rdmain(this.i31Handle, &myString);
```

Comment: It may be important to note that you can only dereference a pointer if you are in an unsafe block, and the C# compiler will only let you use unsafe code if you explicitly tell it to. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Arguments
FlibHndl   [ in ] 
Specify the library handle. See "Library handle" for details. 

file_path   [ out ] 
Specify the pointer for the string that stores "Current drive + folder + file name".
 Allocate 244 byte length for the string maximum size of 242 characters. The string is NULL terminated.

Comment: Possibly this might help you to understand the Arguments needed in the cnc_pdf_rdmain

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following suggestion:

```
[DllImport("FWLIB64.dll", EntryPoint="cnc_pdf_rdmain")]

public static unsafe extern short cnc_pdf_rdmain( ushort FlibHndl, [ Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.AsAny ) ] out Object a );

Object mg1 = new object( );
rslt = Focas64.cnc_pdf_rdmain(this.i31Handle, out mg1 );
if ( rslt != 0 )
{
  StopActivity( true );
  return;
}
string result = mg1.ToString( );
Console.WriteLine( result );
```

Comment: I have tried this already and it throws this exception: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in SpaceX - DragonHPC.exe

Additional information: Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': AsAny cannot be used on return types, ByRef parameters, ArrayWithOffset, or parameters passed from unmanaged to managed.

Comment: `AsAny` is kind of a cheap placeholder and doesn't always work as you might expect.  I don't usually get into pinvoke/export stuff within .NET, but if you have a technical doc (showing the expected datatype, probably in C/C++), that'd help.  Otherwise, if using 32bit, try changing that `AsAny` to an int type (or, if 64bit, try the long type).  Those are the basic C-style pointer types, then pass the `&myString` pointer along to it (don't feel back, this stuff can be a real pain, especially for the uninitiated)

Answer (score 0):

The dllimport line is weird. I'm not sure why FANUC gave you that, when the type is known (char*). There is a straightforward procedure for marshalling a string to char*. You'll need to know if the char* is ANSI or wide encoded too.

Usually you would use something like `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`, i.e.

```
[DllImport ("does-not-exist")]
private static extern void Foo (
      [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string ansiString)
```

Also, you will want to size the string first so there is space to write to it. So make the string 244 characters long

```
string s = new string(' ',244);
Focas64.cnc_pdf_rdmain(this.i31Handle, s);
```

It's been a while. I just refreshed my knowledge [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/).

Comment: Hopefully this works. I will be able to test it in 2 hours. There is no power to the CNC machines at the moment =(

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are using the correct Fanuc function for what you want to do.
The function cnc_pdf_rdmain is used to get the path of the main program registered on the machine.  You cannot influence it with this function and you cannot download it with this function.  It only tells you the path.

I have this working in VB.net

First from the Fanuc documentation:

```
#include "fwlib32.h" or "fwlib64.h"
FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_pdf_rdmain(unsigned short FlibHndl, char *file_path);
```

And the VB declaration:

```
Declare Function cnc_pdf_rdmain Lib "FWLIB32.DLL" _
    ( ByVal FlibHndl As Integer, <[In], Out> ByVal a() As Char ) As Short
```

(This is pre-delivered from Fanuc)

Now in my application:

```
Dim mpPath As Char()
ReDim mpPath(212)

LastError = cnc_pdf_rdmain(Hndl, mpPath)
```

(LastError was defined as an Integer, and Hndl is the handle to the Focas connection that was established earlier.   Note the size of the Char array is specified in the Fanuc documentation)

This will return a string in mpPath that looks something like: "//CNC_MEM/1234" if program 1234 is loaded as the main program from the top level directory.